# Android: Facebook Graph Api v1.0

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK 3.16 for my application. Application registered before April 30th (2014), so I basically should have access to Graph Api v1.0. But when i login via application i can use only Graph Api v2+. I don't want it. How can I get access for Graph Api v1.0?

p.s. Via Graph Api Explorer all is ok. So i am confused

Comment: It is recommended to use Graph Api v2+ henceforth so you can prevent application to use deprecated methods

Comment: Even if there were a way to access the Graph API v1, which, personally, I no longer use, I wouldn't recommened using it. Apps using the older version can run until 30th April 2015 [_Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)_. Upgrading before that deadline allows plenty of time to develop and test.

Comment: @SiddharthLele i know it. But now i need to use only Graph API v1.0

Comment: @user3104216: Again, it's never recommended using a _soon-to-obsolete API_. But if you really want to continue using it, this could part of the FB documentation might help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#androidcalls. I simply don't have any code from the older API anymore to help you out. Besides your post is rather generic as against as specific code using the v1 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I found a solution for my problem.

If you are interested:

I had to get a list of friends.So i did like:

```
protected void getFacebookFriends() {
    new Request(
            session,
            "me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                        JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

It returned me all users who logged in my application.

So i simply added version Graph Api in `Request` like:

```
    new Request(
            session,
            "/v1.0/me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                        JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

And it returned list of all my friends ! But it works if your application registered before  April 30th (2014) and it will deprecated at 30th April 2015