# Getting friends birthdays after Facebook SDK update

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I´m building an app that must show the birthday of all my friends/contacts without them needing to have my app installed or be subscribed to my service.

I was thinking about using Facebook SDK for this, but after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u) that their [latest version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq) doesn´t allow to get data from people who hasn't already installed my app I am having a hard time trying to figure out a viable alternative.

I have checked all the related questions here but most of them are either talking about previous SDK versions or saying it is impossible to do it with the latest version.

Question: Is there still a way to get this information through Facebook or should I look for an alternative way/platform? If so, which alternatives do you recommend that would display the birth date of as many contacts as possible who hasn't installed my app?

**EDIT**: As Tobi has correctly confirmed, right now you can only see the data of friends who are already registered inside your app. I guess it will be hard to find an alternative platform where you can access the birthdays of your contacts.

You can see how to access the data of your (registered) friends in the next question: [Android: Facebook Graph Api v1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066183/android-facebook-graph-api-v1-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the introduction of the Graph API v2.0, it is no longer possible to get access to friends data:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

> All `friends_*` permissions have been removed